# Что знает svn сервер о свойстве keywords клиента?

Tags: svn

Хотелось бы в `hook'е pre-commit` проверять, задано ли на клиенте, делающем `commit` версионированного файла, свойство `keyword = Revision`, и запрещать `commit` с не настроенного клиента. Может кто-то знает, утилиты для `svn`-сервера, читающие настройки клиента? Или есть какой-нибудь другой способ отслеживать эту ситуацию? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Почитал [документацию](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/props/special/keywords/). Похоже ничего он не знает. Цитата:

> Keep in mind that keyword expansion is a **client-side operation**, and your client “knows” only about changes that have occurred in the repository when you update your working copy to include those changes.

(ключевое выделено мною).

> Может кто-то знает, утилиты для svn-сервера, читающие настройки клиента?

согласитесь, это было немного странно.

> Или есть какой-нибудь другой способ отслеживать эту ситуацию?

Да, и Вы его сами назвали - `pre-commit hook`. Почитайте для начала две статьи [hook pre-commit в svn. Реализация на питоне.](http://zadoev.blogspot.com/2008/10/hook-pre-commit-svn.html) и [Perl::Critic + Subversion = внедрение единых практик кодирования в команде](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115395/).

svn будет передавать некоторые кол-во информации о коммите и собственно сам текст коммита. Придется написать скрипт, который будет вытаскивать ревизию с файла, который коммитят и сравнивать с желаемой. Где взять "желаемую"? Если я правильно помню svn, то ревизия меняется на каждый коммит. Значит можно сверять ее с предыдущей, которую можно сохранить заведомо. Но я не уверен в том, что я понимаю это правильно.

Comment: большое-большое спасибо!

Comment: Смысл задачи состоял в том, чтобы клиент не мог положить текст модуля без раскрытого ключа. Иначе в архив мог попасть файл с "типа раскрытым" ключом, который является на самом деле просто текстом, который реально раскрыл предыдущий клиент, скоммитивший этот модуль. Т.е. получалось, что если commit сделан из папки без свойства keyword, то, взяв из svn модули (например для релиза), я получаю ненастоящие версии файлов.

Comment: Вручную, конечно, все можно 
проконтролировать, а хотелось это все автоматизировать. Вот и пришла идея запретить делать commit клиенту без keywords на этапе pre-commit. Сейчас пока удалось обойти эту проблему (поставленная задача изменилась), но интерес остался. Будет время - буду копать.